# Javascript: Assign value for input box in other frame not working in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

I have problem with assigning value to input box located in other frame when view using MS Edge. No problem though when view using IE. So, kindly advise if there any workaround/solution to this problem.

Here is a sample exhibiting the issue: http://thebeebs.github.io/so-35720658/

Code:

index.html Frameset:

```
<frameset rows="20%,*> id="run-detail-frame">
    <frame name="runDetailMain" id="runDetailMain" src="detail.html" ></frame>
    <frame name="runDetailSub" id="runDetailSub" src="custlist.html"></frame>
</frameset>
```

detail.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form name="routeForm">
        <input type="text" class="textbox" name="q_cust_no" size="40" maxlength="40">
        </form>
</body>
```

custlist.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <button id="start">Click to fire function</button>
   <script>
       document.getElementById("start").onclick = function(){
           selectCustomer("Hello")

       }
       function selectCustomer(cust_cd){          
           parent.document.frames["runDetailMain"].routeForm.q_cust_no.value = cust_cd;               
       }
       </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Post the code as text not as a image

Comment: When asking questions on SO it's really helpful to provide a minimal example and either provide full working code or a public URL. It took me about 20 minutes to create the following repro from your image (which is time I could have speant to trying to figure out the issue). For anyone trying to Investigate this issue. I have created a small sample project: https://github.com/thebeebs/so-35720658 which I am using to try and find a solution.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: I've added a link to the issue that I used when creating the answer below. It demonstrates the issue. It works in IE but not Edge or Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code inside of the function selectCustomer to be:

```
parent.frames["runDetailMain"].routeForm.q_cust_no.value = cust_cd;
```

In your code you are calling parent.**document**.frames.

I have a repro that contain working code over on GitHub: https://github.com/thebeebs/so-35720658/tree/master/solution

And a working demo: http://thebeebs.github.io/so-35720658/solution

Calling parent.**document**.frames seems to work in IE but not in Edge and Chrome. Edge has made lots of changes recently and where behaviour is different from other browsers or standards then the Edge team have chosen to remove the behaviour rather than maintain backwards compatibility with IE.

Comment: Apologies for not providing the code in text. I did try to provide the code as text but always give me error when i tried to post. Just still not able to figure out how to do it.

But the most important thing, thanks for the solution as it works like charm. Really appreciate your time spent to solve this problem :)

Comment: No worries. I remember what it was like to be new here, which is why I went to the effort of fixing the question. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)